# Use Ajax request on LinkPager rendered by renderAjax

Tags: php, ajax, pagination, yii2

Basically, I use common AJAX techniques on *action1* to send a request to *action2* and then get the generated data and display on *action1*.

In *action2* accessed by simple JS AJAX request, I return a page rendered by *renderAjax*, and display that HTML returned into some *div* element in the page of *action1*. That's okay. But if I try to use pagination (LinkPager) when I click on the next page link the plugin reload the page and redirect to the *action2* page.

What I want is to make the pagination possible without reload, and into the page of *action1*. The pagination is the *action2* AJAX rendered page.

OBS1: I already tried to use simple PJAX.

OBS2: I cant use GridView because of the layout I want.

Comment: Hello, did you managed to fix this?

Comment: Yes, it's been some time, but if i remeber correctly, i used the LinkPager inside Pjax (wrapping all the content) with "enablePushState => false" and "timeout => false" options.
Then in JS you can call "$.pjax.reload({container: '#your-pjax-id'});" to reload everything when needed. I hope it with helps you somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your table in [pjax](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html) and use it.

Comment: It is not so simple, but it goes something like this. It needed some more settings, but it really was necessary to wrap all content with "Pjax". Thanks a lot.